# Create borders current navigation

Tags: 2013, css, current-navigation

I want to create borders between items of current navigation.
I don't know what class to catch and call in css, any help?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this CSS selector

```
.ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox li.static a {
 border-top: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
}
```